# filter json data in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, azure-databricks

Below code gives me a list of Json Outputs. I would like to get an Output where my Json key value of username is not "system:serviceaccount:internal". and also I would like to filter on timestamp field to get my data? How can I do it.

Here is the code and resultant output:

```py
import re
import json
%pip install azure
import azure
from azure.storage.blob import AppendBlobService

abs = AppendBlobService(account_name="azdevstoreforlogs", account_key="mykey")
base_path = "resourceId=/SUBSCRIPTIONS/subscriptionid/RESOURCEGROUPS/AZURE-DEV/PROVIDERS/MICROSOFT.CONTAINERSERVICE/MANAGEDCLUSTERS/AZURE-DEV"
pattern = base_path + "/*/*/*/*/m=00/*.json"
filter = glob2re(pattern)
df1 = (
    spark.sparkContext.parallelize(
        [
            blob.name
            for blob in abs.list_blobs("insights-logs-kube-audit", prefix=base_path)
            if re.match(filter, blob.name)
        ]
    )
    .map(
        lambda blob_name: abs.get_blob_to_bytes("insights-logs-kube-audit", blob_name)
        .content.decode("utf-8")
        .splitlines()
    )
    .flatMap(lambda lines: [json.loads(l) for l in lines])
    .toDF()
    .take(10)
)
```

Resultant sample output:

```
[
    Row(
        Cloud="AzureCloud",
        Environment="prod",
        UnderlayClass="hcp-underlay",
        UnderlayName="hcp-undx-624",
        category="kube-audit",
        ccpNamespace="540f",
        operationName="Microsoft.ContainerService/managedClusters/diagnosticLogs/Read",
        properties={
            "pod": "kube-api8d8",
            "stream": "stdout",
            "log": '{"kind":"Event","apiVersion":"audit.k8s.io/v1","level":"Metadata","auditID":"ba3","stage":"ResponseComplete","requestURI":"/apis/chaos-mesh.org/v1alpha1/namespaces/veo/httpchaos?limit=500","verb":"list","user":{"username":"system:serviceaccount:internal","uid":"3f35e","groups":["system:serviceaccounts","system:serviceaccounts:internal-services","system:authenticated"]},"sourceIPs":["35.xyz.uye.asz"],"userAgent":"kubectl/v1.18.10 (linux/amd64) kubernetes/62fc","objectRef":{"resource":"httpchaos","namespace":"velero","apiGroup":"chaos-mesh.org","apiVersion":"v1alpha1"},"responseStatus":{"metadata":{},"code":200},"requestReceivedTimestamp":"2022-05-23T13:45:13.140759Z","stageTimestamp":"2022-05-23T13:45:13.146101Z","annotations":{"authentication.k8s.io/legacy-token":"system:serviceaccount:internal","authorization.k8s.io/decision":"allow","authorization.k8s.io/reason":"RBAC: allowed by ClusterRoleBinding \\"cluster-admin\\" of ClusterRole \\"cluster-admin\\" to ServiceAccount \\"spin/internal-services\\""}}\n',
        },
        resourceId="/SUBSCRIPTIONS/533AEB/RESOURCEGROUPS/AZURE-DEV/PROVIDERS/MICROSOFT.CONTAINERSERVICE/MANAGEDCLUSTERS/AZURE-DEV",
        time="2022-05-23T13:45:13.0000000Z",
    ),
    Row(
        Cloud="AzureCloud",
        Environment="prod",
        UnderlayClass="hcp-underlay",
        UnderlayName="hcp-undx-624",
        category="kube-audit",
        ccpNamespace="540f",
        operationName="Microsoft.ContainerService/managedClusters/diagnosticLogs/Read",
        properties={
            "pod": "kube-api8d8",
            "stream": "stdout",
            "log": '{"kind":"Event","apiVersion":"audit.k8s.io/v1","level":"Metadata","auditID":"ba3","stage":"ResponseComplete","requestURI":"/apis/chaos-mesh.org/v1alpha1/namespaces/veo/httpchaos?limit=500","verb":"list","user":{"username":"system:serviceaccount:internal","uid":"3f35e","groups":["system:serviceaccounts","system:serviceaccounts:internal-services","system:authenticated"]},"sourceIPs":["35.xyz.uye.asz"],"userAgent":"kubectl/v1.18.10 (linux/amd64) kubernetes/62fc","objectRef":{"resource":"httpchaos","namespace":"velero","apiGroup":"chaos-mesh.org","apiVersion":"v1alpha1"},"responseStatus":{"metadata":{},"code":200},"requestReceivedTimestamp":"2022-05-23T13:45:13.156899Z","stageTimestamp":"2022-05-23T13:45:13.162219Z","annotations":{"authentication.k8s.io/legacy-token":"system:serviceaccount:internal","authorization.k8s.io/decision":"allow","authorization.k8s.io/reason":"RBAC: allowed by ClusterRoleBinding \\"cluster-admin\\" of ClusterRole \\"cluster-admin\\" to ServiceAccount \\"spin/internal-services\\""}}\n',
        },
        resourceId="/SUBSCRIPTIONS/533AEB/RESOURCEGROUPS/AZURE-DEV/PROVIDERS/MICROSOFT.CONTAINERSERVICE/MANAGEDCLUSTERS/AZURE-DEV",
        time="2022-05-23T13:45:13.0000000Z",
    ),
]
```

Comment: requestReceivedTimestamp, stageTimestamp or time you want to filter on?

Comment: time will be good

Answer (score 0):

After .toDF() you can add below code to extract and then filter username and as time is already there you can filter it directly

```py
.withColumn("logi",F.from_json(F.col("properties.log"),MapType(StringType(),StringType()))).withColumn("logi2",F.from_json(F.col("logi.user"),MapType(StringType(),StringType()))).filter ("logi2.username !='system:serviceaccount:internal' and cast(time as timestamp) > '2022-05-23'").drop(*["logi","logi2"]).show()
```

you can change your filter condition as per requirement
Here for getting username i am creating a column having log data as a map and then got user data as map from it